# How to iterate over multiple arrays - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays in my code as below

```
names = ['Kelvin', 'James'];
age = ['9','10'];
```

When iterate over the arrays, i append the data to a table. This is what i want to have my table look like after i iterate

```
Name    Age

Kelvin   9

James    10
```

But my table looks like this

```
Name    Age

Kelvin   9

Kelvin   10

James    9

James    10
```

**File.Js**

```
  age = localStorage.getItem('age').split(',');
  name = localStorage.getItem('name').split(',');
  if(name != '')
        {
            if(age != '')
            {
                $.each(name, function(index,name_value){
                $.each(age, function(index, age_value){


                $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append('<tr><td >'+name_value+'</td><td >'+age_value+'</td></tr>');
                });
            });
            }


        }
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Use plain `for` loop and access both arrays using single index value

Comment: Use unique index names in `$.each` looper, add condition `if(index1 == index2){ /* append */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate over one array and get get value from second array using the index. In your current scenario you are doing nested loop that means it will iterate `n x n` times which is completely unnecessary.

```
age = localStorage.getItem('age').split(',');
name = localStorage.getItem('name').split(',');

if(name.length && age.length){
   $.each(name, function(index,name_value){
       $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append('<tr><td >'+name_value+'</td><td >'+age[index]+'</td></tr>');
   });
}
```

---

Instead of appending in each iteration you can append after creating entire html string.

```
age = localStorage.getItem('age').split(',');
name = localStorage.getItem('name').split(',');

if(name.length && age.length){
   $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append(name.reduce(function(html, name_value, i){
       return html + '<tr><td >'+name_value+'</td><td >'+age[i]+'</td></tr>';
   }, ''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have always exactly the same amount of elements in both arrays then maybe you can try using index and iterating only once like the following:

```
$.each(name, function(index,name_value) {
    $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append('<tr><td >'+ name[index] +'</td><td >' + age[index] + '</td></tr>');
});
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating twice (one for the `name` variable and one for the `age` variable).

If you are sure that the arrays stored in `name` and `age` have the same size you can just iterate over one of them and use the iteration index to access the other element:

```
$.each(name, function(index, name_value){
    var age_value = age[index];

    $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append('<tr><td >'+name_value+'</td><td >'+age_value+'</td></tr>');
});
```

---

Also, your code presents some uncontrolled things:

1. You are retrieving data from `localStorage`, but you are not checking if there is no data:

```
age = localStorage.getItem('age')
```

can return null if no data is stored in `localStorage`. In this case, your code will break as you will be calling `split` method from null.

2. The way you check if `age` and `name` are empty is a bit confusing. You would be better checking its length:

```
if (name.length > 0)
```

3. If you are storing the data in `localStorage` I would recommend you to store `age` and `name` together, under the same key:

```
localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify([
    { name: 'Kelvin', age: 9 },
    { name: 'James', age: 10 }
]));
```

So that you are sure that when you retrieve the info, you have the same number of items for `name` and `age`:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('users') || '[]';
var users = JSON.parse(data);
if (users.length > 0) {
    $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append(users.map(function(user) {
        return '<tr><td >'+ user.name+'</td><td >'+user.age+'</td></tr>';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use single iterate instead of nested iterate:

```
$.each(name, function(index,name_value) {
   $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append('<tr><td >'+ name_value +'</td><td >' + age[index] + '</td></tr>');
});
```